# How do I increase the value of counter in app A from app B

Tags: android, kotlin

Let's take a practical scenario to understand what I want to achieve.

There is a bar in the town that keeps a record of how many people are in the bar and how many people have left the bar.

The bar uses an app to display these numbers to the manager inside his office.

And there is a gatekeeper that has another app with him to count people.

He taps on the 'add' button to increment and the 'left' button to decrement whenever anybody leaves or enters the bar.

I want the numbers on the manager app to sync with the bodyguards app to show how many people entered and left.

Just tell me what to use. I will learn the implementation.

Comment: Standard option is to push the data to a server from app A and pull it from app B. Another option could be direct communication if both devices are on the same LAN. In any case, you need a way to communicate both devices.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I do it if both devices are connected to the same Wifi router?